# What is the relation between the gradient and the Jacobian matrix here?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

For $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$
$$
f(x) = \frac 1 2 \left\Vert g(x)\right\Vert^2_2
$$

How to show that
$$
\nabla f(x) = J_g(x)^T g(x)
$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}[(g_{1}(x))^{2}+\cdots+(g_{m}(x))^{2}],
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(x)&=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot2\left[g_{1}(x)\dfrac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x_{i}}(x)+\cdots+g_{m}(x)\dfrac{\partial g_{m}}{\partial x_{i}}(x)\right]\\
&=g_{1}(x)\dfrac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x_{i}}(x)+\cdots+g_{m}(x)\dfrac{\partial g_{m}}{\partial x_{i}}(x),
\end{align*}
the rest is just writing down the big matrix.

Comment: Ah, thanks a bunch! Writing out the sum from the norm definition definitely helped, I also did that just now. However, I can't edit your answer because I need to edit a certain amount of characters, but you're missing the index 1 at $$ g_1(x) \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_i}(x) $$.

Answer (score 0):

It is an application of chain rule. Let $\varphi: y \mapsto (\sum_{1}^{m}y_{i}^{2})/2$; then 
$$
f: x \mapsto g(x) =: y \mapsto \varphi(y), \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}.
$$
So,
given that the conclusion of your interest takes that form, we have
$$
\nabla f(x) = (\nabla \varphi(y)' Dg(x))^{\top} = ((y_{1}, \dots, y_{m})Dg(x))^{\top} = Dg(x)^{\top}g(x).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
f(x) = \frac12\left\Vert g(x)\right\Vert^2_2 = \frac12\langle g(x),g(x)\rangle.
$$
and apply [Frechet derivative for bilinear map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677124/frechet-derivative-for-bilinear-map).