# What is the derivative of absolute value of a complex number?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

Consider a function $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(z) = |z|^2$. What is the first order derivative of $f(z)$? And what is the gradient of $f(z)$?

I found in the [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), it said that the  gradient of $f(z)$ is $2z$. Is there any difference between gradient and first order derivative?

Comment: It isn't complex differentiable, only real differentiable

Comment: What, in your opinion, is the "first order derivative" of a given function $g:\>{\mathbb C}\to{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: Treat the function $f$ as a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. How would you differentiate such a function?

Comment: "Is there any difference between gradient and first order derivative?" Essentially are the same, but...The derivative/differential in a point of $f:\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is a *linear function* (row vector in the usual notation). The gradient in a point of the same $f$ is a *vector*  (column vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f = g\circ h$ with
$$g:\Bbb C\times\Bbb C\longrightarrow\Bbb C,\qquad(w,z)\longmapsto w\bar z$$
real [bilinear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677124/frechet-derivative-for-bilinear-map)
and
$$h:\Bbb C\longrightarrow\Bbb C\times\Bbb C\qquad z\longmapsto (z,z)$$
real (and complex) linear.

Comment: To be picky: $g$ is sesquilinear and real bilinear only.

Comment: @user251257, edited.