# Prove $f(x)=x\|x\|$ is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to prove that $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, 
$$f(x)=x\|x\|$$
is differentiable as a part of a larger task.

I think there  two ways to approach this:

1. By proving that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ there is a linear function $A$ for which 
   $$f(x+h)=f(x)+Ah+\|h\|\epsilon(h)$$
   where $\epsilon(h)\rightarrow0$ when $h\rightarrow0$
2. By proving that all of the first order partial derivatives of $f$ exist and are continuous.

For the sake of my own understanding, I would like to know how to prove this with both of the ways. Here are my attempts so far:

1. $f(x+h)=(x_{1}\sqrt{x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2}+h_{1},x_{2}\sqrt{x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2}+h_{2})=(x_{1}\sqrt{x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2},x_{2}\sqrt{x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2})+(h_{1},h_{2})=f(x)+(h_{1},h_{2})$

I don't know how to go on with this since I'm not sure how I'm supposed to choose $A$. If $f$ is differentiable, $A$ should be $Df(x)$ but I don't know how should I manipulate the expression to achieve that.

2. For the second way, I'm not sure how to write out the general form of the first order partial derivatives for $f$.

Comment: For $x \ne 0$ (see José Carlos Santos's answer for $x = 0$), one could argue that $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $(x, y) \mapsto \langle x, y \rangle$ is bilinear, so differentiable, with derivative $(h, k) \mapsto \langle x, k \rangle + \langle h, y \rangle$; so $\|x\|^2 = \langle x, x \rangle$ is differentiable, with derivative $h \mapsto 2\langle x, h \rangle$; so $\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$ is differentiable, with derivative $h \mapsto \langle x, h \rangle/\|x\|$; and scalar multiplication is bilinear, so $f'(x)(h) = \langle x, h \rangle x/\|x\| + \|x\|h$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Part 1.*
Here is a derivation (no pun intended) of $f'(x)(h)$ from first
principles. It is valid not just in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but in any real inner
product space $E$, not necessarily even finite-dimensional. ($E$ is
not even assumed to be complete; but if it isn't, then I don't think
one is allowed to speak of $f$ being "differentiable" at $x$.)

First, we make some estimates:

(i) By the Triangle Inequality,
$\lvert\lVert x + h \rVert - \lVert x \rVert\rvert \leqslant
\lVert h \rVert$.

(ii) If $x \ne 0$, then by (i), as $h \to 0$,
$$
\left\lvert\frac{2}{\lVert x + h \rVert + \lVert x \rVert}
- \frac{1}{\lVert x \rVert}\right\rvert =
\frac{\lvert\lVert x \rVert - \lVert x + h \rVert\rvert}
{(\lVert x + h \rVert + \lVert x \rVert)\lVert x \rVert}
\leqslant \frac{\lVert h \rVert}{\lVert x \rVert^2} =
O(\lVert h \rVert).
$$

(iii) The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$\lvert\left\langle x, h \right\rangle\rvert \leqslant
\lVert x \rVert \lVert h \rVert$ gives
$\left\langle x, h \right\rangle = O(\lVert h \rVert)$.

Now, for all $x, h \in E$,
\begin{align*}
f(x + h) - f(x) & = \lVert x + h \rVert(x + h) - \lVert x \rVert x
\\ & = \lVert x \rVert h +
(\lVert x + h \rVert - \lVert x \rVert)(x + h)
\\ & = \lVert x \rVert h +
(\lVert x + h \rVert - \lVert x \rVert)x + O(\lVert h \rVert^2),
&& \text{by (i).}
\end{align*}
This proves that $f'(x)(h) = 0$ for all $h$ when $x = 0$. From now
on, we assume that $x \ne 0$.
\begin{gather*}
f(x + h) - f(x) - \lVert x \rVert h =
\frac{\lVert x + h \rVert^2 - \lVert x \rVert^2}
{\lVert x + h \rVert + \lVert x \rVert}x +
O(\lVert h \rVert^2)
\\ =
\frac{2\left\langle x, h \right\rangle + \lVert h \rVert^2}
{\lVert x + h \rVert + \lVert x \rVert}x +
O(\lVert h \rVert^2)
=
\frac{2}{\lVert x + h \rVert + \lVert x \rVert}
\left\langle x, h \right\rangle x +
O(\lVert h \rVert^2)
\\ =
\frac{\left\langle x, h \right\rangle}{\lVert x \rVert}x +
\left(\frac{2}{\lVert x + h \rVert + \lVert x \rVert} -
\frac{1}{\lVert x \rVert}\right)
\left\langle x, h \right\rangle x +
O(\lVert h \rVert^2).
\end{gather*}
Therefore, by (ii) and (iii),
$$
f(x + h) = f(x) + \lVert x \rVert h +
\frac{\left\langle x, h \right\rangle}{\lVert x \rVert}x +
O(\lVert h \rVert^2).
$$

<sup>This agrees with the formula for $f'(x)(h)$ in my earlier brief comment.
(The main result used there - apart from the Chain Rule, and the formula for
the derivative of the square root function on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ - is
[Frechet derivative for bilinear map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677124).)</sup>

---

*Part 2.*
For simplicity [but at some risk of confusion with the earlier use of the symbol
'$x$'!], I'll use the notation $(x, y)$, instead of $(x_1, x_2)$, and write
$$
(u, v) = f(x, y) = r(x, y) = (rx, ry),
\text{ where } r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.
$$

The case $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ was dealt with in an earlier answer, but as that
answer has now been deleted, I'll go over the same ground here.

We have $f(h, 0) = (h|h|, 0)$, $f(0, k) = (0, k|k|)$, and so
\begin{align*}
|u(h, 0)| & = h^2, \ v(h, 0) = 0, \\
|v(0, k)| & = k^2, \ u(0, k) = 0,
\end{align*}
showing that the partial derivatives
$D_1u(0, 0)$, $D_1v(0, 0), D_2v(0, 0)$, $D_2u(0, 0)$ exist, and are all zero.

Assume now that $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$. Then $r > 0$, and
$\partial r/\partial x = x/r$, $\partial r/\partial y = y/r$, whence
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} h \\ k \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{x^2}{r} + r & \frac{xy}{r} \\
\frac{xy}{r} & \frac{y^2}{r} + r 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} h \\ k \end{pmatrix} =
r \begin{pmatrix} h \\ k \end{pmatrix} +
\frac{xh + yk}{r} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix},
$$
in agreement with the previous result.

In a convenient but admittedly loose notation, simply denoting the
separate convergence of all four matrix entries,
$$
\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} 
\end{pmatrix} =
\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{x^2}{r} + r & \frac{xy}{r} \\
\frac{xy}{r} & \frac{y^2}{r} + r 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
showing that all four partial derivatives are continuous everywhere. $\square$